# Spring Boot - How to register Bean programmatically and efficiently from a large CSV file (not using @Bean to method)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, initialization

I have a large CSV file which contains all the data, I need to create several @Beans based on that file. To be efficient, after reading the file into memory, I want to loop it once (as less as possible) to create all the beans. If I use @Bean on the method, that would cause multiple for-loop because in each method I have to take one loop. Instead, is there a way that I use a standalone method to loop the data once and register all the beans programmatically?

This is what I expected, is there a method similar to registerAsBean()?

```java
public void processData(List<String[]> data) {

List<Cat> bean1;
List<Dog> bean2;

for (String[] row: data) {
   Cat cat = new Cat(row[0]);
   Dog dog = new Dog(row[1]);
   bean1.add(cat);
   bean2.add(dog);
}

registerAsBean(bean1);
registerAsBean(bean2);

return;

}
```

This is a conventional way which takes multiple loops.

```java
@Bean(name="bean1")
public List<Cat> createBean1(List<String[]> data) {

List<Cat> bean1;

for (String[] row: data) {
   Cat cat = new Cat(row[0]);
   bean1.add(cat);
}

return bean1;

}

@Bean(name="bean2")
public List<Dog> createBean2(List<String[]> data) {

List<Dog> bean2;

for (String[] row: data) {
   Dog dog = new Dog(row[1]);
   bean2.add(dog);
}

return bean2;

}
```

I have tried GenericWebApplicationContext.registerBean() which needs Beans class as param. One of my Bean class is List so it is not convenient to get the class.

I expect that in the initializaion of Spring Boot, all the beans could be created as efficient as possible through a large CSV file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.